# Velocity vector and Distance traveled function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, parametric

Im studying Multivariable calculus from this video: Lec 6 | MIT 18.02 Multivariable Calculus, Fall 2007 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0D4BbCa4gHo&index=6&list=PL4C4C8A7D06566F38&pbjreload=10)

he define a function called s(t) which is a distance travelled along the arc length at minute 17:00

then at minute 23:00 he defines the velocity vector written in the form:

$$\vec{v} = \frac{ d \vec{r}}{ds}*\frac{ ds}{dt} = \hat{T} * |\vec{v}|$$

then he said:

$$ \Delta{\vec{r}} \approx \hat{T} \Delta{s}$$

then at minute 26:12 - 26:22 only in this 10 seconds i think what is said is wrong.

he said "This vector here I will call delta R, the length of this vector is delta S" this is wrong and to be correct he have to say "the length of this vector is approximately delta S"

because if S is a function defined by the distance travelled at time t then $$\Delta{s} = s(t + \Delta{t}) - s(t)$$

which in english is "distance travelled at time t plus delta t minus distance travelled at time t" the word "distance travelled" is measured from the arc not from the straight line. The vector $\Delta{\vec{r}}$ is measured in straight line from point $r(t+ \Delta{t})-r(t)$ which will not have the length equal to $\Delta{s}$ in the case that the trajectory is curved.

i know that after he takes the limit as $\Delta{t} \to \infty$  of :

$$\frac{ \Delta{\vec{r}}}{ \Delta{t} } \approx \hat{T} * \frac{ \Delta{s}}{ \Delta{t} }$$

you get:

$$\vec{v} =  \hat{T} * |\vec{v}|$$

but I just want to really understand it in a correct way.
Am I understand correctly that he should say "the length of vector delta R is approximately delta S"? which also means before taking the limit in this formula:

$$ \Delta{\vec{r}} \approx \hat{T} \Delta{s}$$

we multiply $\hat{T}$ by the length of the arc travelled from point $r(t)$ to $r(t+\Delta{t})$  not the length of the vector $\Delta{\vec{r}}$

Comment: I wouldn't say it is wrong, just semantics really, if everything is taken so small as to be approximately close it doesn't really matter, this is standard in approximating a curved segment with a straight one, and is taken care of with the second equation you've written. Really it's just less precise than what you've said. Honestly if you want to limit confusion of course you might want to make sure your readers understand that by equality you mean approximately which is what I assume the writer means.

Comment: @Triatticus so in conclusion, before taking the limit, the length of $\Delta{\vec{r}}$ is not equal to $\Delta{s}$  but approximately equal to  $\Delta{s}$  Am I understand correctly? I understand what happen after taking the limit but my question is focusing on before taking the limit. because if you watch from the video what professor says (minute 26:12 - 26:22) is before taking the limit.

Comment: Yes I'm aware, certainly it's more accurate to not say exactly equal but it's likely they assume you understand that it's equality but only approximately and that's fine